# Extjs getting fields values from extended FormPanel

Tags: forms, extjs

The submit button for my formPanel works by using scope:this as it is an extended formPanela nd ext.getCmp(formid) doesn't work.

In my submit function, it successfully works using this.getForm().submit(....). However when trying to get the field values, this.getForm().getFields() doesn't work, flagging that it is not a function.

the buttons & handler function is nested within the formPanel setup.

Can anyone shed light on how to get the values in this manner?

Submit function:

```
{
    text: 'Submit',
    id: "submitBtn",                    
    handler: this.submit,
    scope: this                    
}
....

,submit : function(url, waitMsg) {
    //this.getForm.getFields()
    this.getForm().submit({
        url: url
        ,scope: this
        ,waitMsg: 'Please wait'
        ,success: this.onSuccess
        //,failure: this.onFailure

    });
}
```

Comment: @Chau I can't see any changes from your edit...

Comment: **@pm13** Click on the time just above my avatar. Here you can see the changes + a brief comment about what I edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
submit : function(url, waitMsg) {
        //this.getForm.getFields() -- should work now
        this.getForm().submit({
            url: url
            ,scope: this
            ,waitMsg: 'Please wait'
            ,success: this.onSuccess
            //,failure: this.onFailure
        });
    }.createDelegate(this)
```

Comment: that didn't work. It returned `code` this.getForm is not a function
[Break On This Error] this.getForm().getFields(); `code` Basically what I need to do is to parse the values & components names into JSON so that a REST Service can be called

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this by not using the submit action but by using a simple Ext.Ajax.request:

```
,submit : function() {
        var data = this.getForm().getValues();
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '...',
            method: 'GET',
            timeout:180000,
            params: {
                param1: Ext.encode(this.getForm().getValues())
            }
            .
        })
```